# Relation between the Tate-Shafarevich group of a number field and the Tate-Shafarevich group of an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-cohomology, tate-shafarevich-groups

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a number field $K$, and let $sha^1(K,E)$ be the Tate-Shafarevich group, defined by:

Let $v$ be a valuation on $K$, and denote by $K_v$ the completion of $K$ by $v$, and for any arbitrary field $F$, $\bar{F}$ is an algebraic closure of $F$. Let $M_K$ be the set of all valuations on $K$, let $E(F)$ be the set of $F$-rational points. We use the notation $H^1(K,E)$ to denote $H^1(Gal(\bar{K}/K),E(K))$ then we have canonically $$H^1(K,E\bar{(K)})\to H^1(K_v,E\bar{(K_v)})$$
given by $K\hookrightarrow K_v$ and $Gal(\bar{K_v}/K_v)\hookrightarrow Gal(\bar{K}/K)$. We shall define:

$$sha^1(K,E):=\bigcap_{v\in M_K}Ker(H^1(K,E\bar{(K)})\to H^1(K_v,E\bar{(K_v)}))$$

or more friendly

$$sha^1(K,E):=Ker(H^1(K,E\bar{(K)})\to \prod_{v\in M_K}H^1(K_v,E\bar{(K_v)}))$$

Let $\mathcal{O}_F$ be the ring of integers of an arbitrary field $F$, then we shall define the Tate-Shafarevich group of the number field $K$:

$$sha^1(K):=\bigcap_{v\in M_K}Ker(H^1(Gal(\bar{K}/K),\mathcal{O}_{\bar{K}}^\times)\to H^1(Gal(\bar{K_v}/K_v),\mathcal{O}_{\bar{K_v}}^\times)))$$

It is known by [this](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2016/REUPapers/Kailasa.pdf) that $sha^1(K)$ is finite (again, $K$ is a number field), but the finiteness of $sha^1(K,E)$ is still a conjecture. Are there any relations between $sha^1(K)$ and $sha^1(K,E)$? it feels weird to me that such close (by definitions) groups might be so structurally different.

Thanks in advance.